# Google wallet inapp payment is not working with phonegap framework

Tags: android, cordova, android-pay

Iam trying to implement the Google wallet digital goods api for mobile web version with PhoneGap framework.

You can find the sample link here[for web site]:
https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial

Its working fine with [google chrome] browser. But its not working in mobile device.

EDIT:
In mobile device If i click on "Buy with Google Wallet" initial screen appears which contains Product title, Quantity along with "Buy Now" button. But after hitting the "Buy Now" button the blank white screen appears with no content in it

Any Ideas ?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: can you please explain whats not working please ? little more details would help to help you.

Comment: In mobile device If i click on "Buy with Google Wallet" initial screen appears which contains Product title, Quantity along with "Buy Now" button. But after hitting the "Buy Now" button the blank white screen appears with no content in it.

Comment: FYI I believe the terms of Android Market & iTunes state something like all digital content meant to be consumed on the phone must use their respective forms of in application purchase.  What are you trying to sell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is assuming you are hosting the mobile web app as a site on the internet, not locally on a device ala phonegap.  I bet if you made the wallet page open in the mobile browser it would work fine.

Comment: Yes.. But iam trying to implement for Phonegap app not as a site on the internet. any ideas ?

Comment: I understand.  I'm doing the same thing, and I agree it would be better to do it in the app.  For my app, its acceptable that when the user clicks "subscribe" or "buy" I will take them to a webpage on my server that finishes payment process in their web browser.

Comment: I'm working on this more tonight. If I manage to get it working in app I'll let you know.

Comment: Sadly opening the purchase window in the mobile browser was the only way I could get it to work, which means hosting that web page on the internet.  This wasn't a big deal for me, but could be unsurmountable I'm sure.  I'm guessing that the issue is that google sets 10-15 cookies with YOUR DOMAIN, and since the domain on phonegap is file:// that likely causes issues with the wallet work flow.
The other option, of course, is in-app android billing, but that will cost you 30%.