# Google Wallet integration with phonegap

Tags: android, gwt, cordova, android-pay

I would like to know who to integrate **google wallet** into **phonegap** 
1. when i click on button it shows item and description and *start now* button
2. by clicking on start now it is showing the white page  in emulator.

resource: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#1

Answer (score 1):

The Google Wallet for digital goods API is a web payment flow, i.e. it requires a browser. It won't work with Phonegap the way you intend to.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600853/google-wallet-inapp-payment-is-not-working-with-phonegap-framework) for more details.

Comment: can you please suggest how to implement it in phone gap any idea

Comment: Are you part of the Google Wallet developer team? If so worth adding this to your profile.